# sql server join joining 3 tables to give highest date out multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, max

I have 3 tables (a, b, c) they are linked by acc_no (a.acc_no, b.acc_no, c.acc_no)

and I'm trying to join them in a way to obtain the highest row value:

```
a.acc_no    a.seq_no    b.open_dt    b.close_dt    c.chg_dt
--------    --------    ---------    ----------    ----------
100001      500         2016-07-01   2016-07-16    2016-09-02
100001      500         2016-07-01   2016-07-16    2016-09-05
100001      510         2016-07-17   2016-09-30    2016-09-02
100001      510         2016-07-17   2016-09-30    2016-09-05
100002      502         2016-09-02   2016-09-27    2016-09-03
100003      503         2016-09-03   2016-09-26    2016-09-25
```

how do i make it look like this:

```
a.acc_no    a.seq_no    b.open_dt    b.close_dt    c.chg_dt
--------    --------    ---------    ----------    ----------
100001      510         2016-07-17   2016-09-30    2016-09-05
100002      502         2016-09-02   2016-09-27    2016-09-03
100003      503         2016-09-03   2016-09-26    2016-09-25
```

basically disregard the lowest a.seq_no where the acc_no is the same and also display the highest chang_dt possible out of the two i'm let with.

I've tried everything but I either don't get it or I'm doing something wrong when I join the tables.

To clarify the tables:

```
TABLE a    TABLE b    TABLE c
-------    -------    -------
acc_no     acc_no     acc_no
seq_no     open_dt    chang_dt
           close_dt
```

all 3 tables are linked by acc_no

Comment: Clarify your question on what your three tables look like.

Comment: Have you tried any query yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
SELECT a.acc_no, 
       Max(a.seq_no), 
       Max(b.open_dt), 
       Max(b.close_dt), 
       Max(c.chang.dt) 
FROM   a 
       JOIN b 
         ON ( a.acc_no = b.acc_no ) 
       JOIN c 
         ON ( b.acc_no = c.acc_no ) 
GROUP  BY a.acc_no
```